# In a string or not?

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing

Recently I've been having [some trouble](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript/issues/16) with the new [TeaScript](https://github.com/vihanb/teascript) interpreter. The biggest problem is identifying whether or not a string contains any special characters.

---

## Challenge

A special character is defined as a character with codepoint 160 to 255. You will be given an input which is a string of characters with codepoints 0 to 255, at most one of which is a special character. The input will consist of a prefix of zero or more characters, a quoted string, and a suffix of zero or more characters. If there is a special character in the quoted string you should output a truthy value, otherwise a falsey value.

### Details

- The characters `"'` are considered quotes.
- Inside the quoted string, a backslash `\` will be used to escape the following character. In the prefix and suffix, it has no special meaning.
- Quotes will always be balanced.
- There will only be one quoted string.

### Examples

```
"Hello, World¡"
true

"Hello, World"¡
false

"Hello' Wo\"rld\\"¡
false

ab"cd\"ef\\gh\i\\"£
false

\"foo¡"
true
```

Comment: This could use a test case where the Unicode character is escaped.

Comment: Also test cases that actually use `'` strings and multiple strings in a single test case (ideally with the Unicode character between them).

Comment: @MartinBüttner One of the rules is that *"There will only be one set of quotes"* but +1 for the other test case ideas.

Comment: @user81655 oh right, I overlooked that. That simplifies things.

Comment: "Because there are only 1,114,112 characters in unicode, your code will need to be as short as possible" ................ I have no words for your golfing justifications.

Comment: I think I can just about work out what you're asking for, but the question almost seems designed to confuse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), <s>19</s> 17 bytes

*Thanks to user81655 for saving 2 bytes.*

Byte count uses ISO 8859-1.

```
['"].*[¡-ÿ].*['"]
```

Output is 0 or 1.

[Try it online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=WyciXS4qW8KhLcO_XS4qWyciXQ&input=XCJmb2_CoSI)

#### Explanation

Due to the assumptions of the challenge, the first `'` or `"` will start the only string of the input and the last `'` or `"` ends it. We also don't need to worry about them being the same because they are guaranteed to be the same anyway.

Therefore, the regex just tries to find a character with code point 161 to 255, inclusive, which is preceded by one quote and followed by another. There will always be either 0 or 1 match.

Comment: Won't this give a false positive for `"abc"¡'`? (I guess depending on how you read the OP, that bare single quote can never occur in an input, but technically there is only one *set* of quotes in this input.)

Comment: @Mauris the spec says that quotes will always be balanced.

Comment: Here's another 17-byte solution: `(['"]).*[¡-ÿ].*\1`. It happens to be more practical.

Comment: @ןnɟuɐɯɹɐןoɯ yeah, I considered that one, but figured it was overkill, given the assumptions of the challenge. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 4):

**Note:** This can be done with a simple regular expression. `` s=>s.match`['"].*[¡-ÿ].*['"]` `` is 29 bytes in JavaScript, but it's more fun without regular expressions:

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>84</s> 82 bytes

```js
s=>[...s].map((c,i)=>q?i<s.lastIndexOf(q)&c>" "?r=1:s:c=="'"|c=='"'?q=c:0,q=r=0)|r
```

### Explanation

Returns `1` for `true` and `0` for `false`. The `" "` in the code below is a `U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE` (code point 160).

```js
s=>
  [...s].map((c,i)=>     // for each character c in the string
    q?
      i<s.lastIndexOf(q) // if we are still inside the string
        &c>" "?r=1       // and c is a "unicode character", set the result to 1 (true)
      :s                 // returning s for false guarantees that the array returned by map
                         //     will cast to NaN, which allows us to use |r instead of &&r
    :c=="'"|c=='"'?      // if we are starting a string
      q=c                // set the end of string character
    :0,
    q=                   // q = end string character
      r=0,               // initialise r to 0 (false)
  )|r                    // return r
```

### Test

```js
var solution = s=>[...s].map((c,i)=>q?i<s.lastIndexOf(q)&c>" "?r=1:s:c=="'"|c=='"'?q=c:0,q=r=0)|r
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value='ab"cd\"ef\\gh\i\\"£' />
<button onclick="result.textContent=solution(input.value)">Go</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Does it handle the backspace to escape quotes?

Comment: What do you mean? You could test it using the test snippet.

Comment: Right. It does in fact

Comment: Oh, your regex is even shorter than my two-stage Retina solution. Do you mind if I use it?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Go ahead. It's pretty much the same anyway.